# Debian, Bluetooth, I can't turn on my bluetooth

Tags: debian, bluetooth

When I turn on bluetooth with the gnome GUI nothing happens.

The button becomes blue, but if I leave and come back the button is normal again.

I tried a bunch of stuff in the cli that I copied from other questions but nothing seemed to work.

[gnome-bluetooth not working properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240537/gnome-bluetooth-not-working-properly)

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

after eexecuting this command, the knob in the gui isn't "on".

https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-bluetooth-in-linux/

when I open blueman it tells me that my bluetooth isn't enabled.

I have very little experience with Linux.

Comment: To be clear, you followed the steps outlined in the link? What is not working specifically? The steps you need to do is install the bluetooth  module, restart your computer, start the bluetooth service, turn on bluetooth, then verify the that the bluetooth service is running and can be paired to. [Please edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/495320/edit) to include the specifics. Thank you!